# В Node.js ES6 модулях не работают в import абсолютные пути?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, модули

Использую модули ES6, все файлы переименовал с расширением .mjs

```
app/
  server.mjs
  node_modules/...
  prog/
    prog.mjs
    client.mjs
    js/
      utils.mjs
```

-- client.mjs

```
import {fun1,fun2} from "./js/utils.mjs";
// или же ставлю абсолютные пути
import {fun1,fun2} from "/prog/js/utils.mjs";
```

www.мойсайт.com/prog/js/utils.mjs - ок
браузер видит все .mjs файлы от корня сайта и всё работает

А в самом Node.js ставлю тоже абсолютные пути и он не находит!

-- prog.mjs

```
import {fun1,fun2} from "./js/utils.mjs";
import {wss}       from "../server.mjs";
// ставлю абсолютные пути
import {fun1,fun2} from "/prog/js/utils.mjs";
import {wss}       from "/server.mjs";
// Error: Cannot find module, code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Когда был require можно было загрузить с диска C:/ но сейчас и так не работает.

```
let {wss} = require("C:/app/server.js");
import {wss} from "C:/app/server.mjs"; // не работает
```

я так понимаю что Node.js считает корневой, папку node_modules/
как мне сделать чтобы он считал корневой, корневую папку app ???

Comment: 1) Что такое расширение `mjs`? Первый раз такое встречаю.
2) Корневой считает директория, в которой лежит ваш проект, а не `node_modules`

Comment: Нода считает корневой папкой корневую папку. Ту самую в которой /home и тп

Answer (score -2):

На сколько я знаю, поддержки ES6 "из коробки" в Node.js нет, поэтому надо использовать какой-нибудь [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) или этого рода. А с абсолютными путями почитай [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

Comment: ну что значит нет? я скачал и установил Node.js 10, всё там есть
я просто добовляю флаг относительные то пути работают >>node --experimental-modules server.mjs

Comment: А пробовал такую штуку: "../../path/to/file.js"?

Comment: блин, ну я же в вопросе написал, что так работает, но мне нужны абсолютные